# python wsgi on windows 7

Tags: python, xampp, wsgi

having followed this thread 3891996/setting-python-path-in-windows-xampp-using-wsgi and gotten xampp to run apache smoothly, when I try to access a sample page created, I get this response:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
10/23/11 13:37:42
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

does anyone know what the deal is?

Answer (score 0):

The presentation:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

explains the two common reasons you would get that message.

The second part of the message suggests the Apache service doesn't have ability to read the directories down to where the WSGI script file is.

Comment: ok but even after reviewing the permissions another question comes up, how do you make apache have permisson to that folder when it is in htdocs and apache already has permission to htdocs and works under php?